# Conditionally grep value from JSON-like key-value pairs in Bash

Tags: json, bash, grep

I'm using an API that returns JSON data. The data is usually missing a few characters at the end, so it's technically "JSON-like" since it's slightly malformed.

I'm able to extract a field of interest from it using `grep` like this in my Bash script:

```
grep -Po '"username": *\K"[^"]*"' jsonraw > jsonclean
```

That works fine despite the JSON being slightly truncated. The only problem is that it returns every single record, whereas I want to make it conditional on another key-value pair.

For example, I want it to only return the `username` value if the `activity_count` field is `>=1`, else just skip the record. Some pseudo-code to represent this might look like:

```
if  '"activity_count":' >=1 grep -Po '"username": *\K"[^"]*"' jsonraw > jsonclean
```

I realize that `jq` might be an easier alternative but I prefer to stick with `grep` because of the malformed end of the JSON data and other reasons.

Sample data:

```
[
{"id":"37da1db11b6b4977902baa286f88bf05","activity_count":0,"blocked":false,"coverPhoto":"cb861013bdcc4e5f9e2a93394a7b4309","followed":true,"human":true,"integration":false,"joined":"20190602125229","muted":false,"name":"AV8R","rss":false,"private":false,"profilePhoto":"511d4625df2442fc9b02ab4279c28f09","subscribed":false,"username":"APALMER66","verified":false,"verifiedComments":false,"badges":[0],"score":"1.4k","interactions":259},{"id":"525f9e87bb2d4f4184d12037050afc8d","activity_count":2,"blocked":false,"coverPhoto":"b0bbb4dec22f40d6a347dfb666ff0158","followed":true,"human":true,"integration":false,"joined":"20200627154134","muted":false,"name":"DeziRay","rss":false,"private":false,"profilePhoto":"86627047425844fcbf921e53fc71d106","subscribed":false,"username":"Deziray","verified":false,"verifiedComments":false,"badges":[0],"score":"4.7k","interactions":259},
```

Expected output:

```
Deziray
```

Comment: FWIW, a jq answer that doesn't care about a malformed end-of-document is feasible, if one uses streaming mode.

Comment: ...alternately, are you okay with Python? There are also stream-based JSON parsers for Python available, such as https://pypi.org/project/jsonslicer/, and it'd be fairly straightforward to build a shell function that wraps a short Python script using one of them.

Comment: I have added sample data. Thanks @CharlesDuffy on the info about `jq` I may consider it if there's not a good `grep` answer, but there were a couple of other reasons I wanted to stick with `grep`, like it's already present in any Linux system so the code would work without having to install it. Same thing for Python, though yes I do happen to love Python personally. I'm just trying to keep the script free of dependencies if I can.

Comment: Are you sure the API is sending malformed data? Maybe the problem is with how you're fetching it.

Comment: @Barmar The reason it's malformed is because I only need the most recent records when the script runs, and the API doesn't support fetching a limited number of records except by cancelling the request in progress (otherwise it will download 10000x more than I need). So I have to run it with `timeout`.

Comment: Heh. I'd be surprised to find a modern Linux system that isn't a special-purpose embedded distro and didn't have Python preinstalled out-of-the-box; your Red Hat and Ubuntu derivatives all use it for OS-vendor-provided tools.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if you have a good Python answer go for it. I can use that for now.

Comment: Is your data all line-oriented, as you're showing here (so everything but the first line is, if the trailing comma is removed, a valid JSON document?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not very familiar with that term, but the data does all look like this. When I pull it from the API if I open it in nano then it's all on 1 long line. I opened this with a GUI text editor so that I could copy it more easily.

Comment: Ahh -- okay, that's a little trickier than what I was thinking then, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: ...added a jq answer to start, will try to see about a Python answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, thanks Charles. I'll accept your jq answer but if you add a Python one I'll give you another upvote and my greatest thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (because it's easier), a `jq` answer:

```
jq -nr --stream '
fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
| select(.activity_count >= 1)
| .username
' <test.json
```

Because this operates in streaming mode, it's able to process even truncated documents.

Comment: This is great, thank you. If anyone has a `grep` answer that would still be useful as well (and I might have to move over the green checkmark - but this works for now, thanks again).

Answer (score 1):

As a native Python implementation, relying on a modern Python 3.x runtime:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json, sys

def found_obj_cb(item):
    if item.get('activity_count', 0) >= 1 and 'username' in item:
        print(item['username'])
    return item

try:
    json.load(sys.stdin, object_hook=found_obj_cb)
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    pass
```

...used from shell as:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

json_parse_py=$(cat <<'EOF'
import json, sys

def found_obj_cb(item):
    if item.get('activity_count', 0) >= 1 and 'username' in item:
        print(item['username'])
    return item

try:
    json.load(sys.stdin, object_hook=found_obj_cb)
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    pass
EOF
)

# define a shell function to wrap the Python code
json_parse() { python3 -c "$json_parse_py" "$@"; }

# actually call it, with test.json on stdin
json_parse <test.python
```